# Configuring angular universal with Asp.NET Core

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

After reading the microsoft docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio), i have seen that we use the `Startup.cs` file to call the `app.UseSpa()` and do some configuration.

On the other hand, while reading the starter project from Mark Pieszak's github repository (https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-angular-universal), I saw no such method call in the `startup.cs` file, the configuration was rather on the Home controller and the views files.

**What is the difference between the two approaches in terms of pros & cons, or simply when to use one or the other?**

Comment: Take a look at  this [line](https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-angular-universal/blob/master/Startup.cs#L71) . The official template always uses the de facto standard way, namely "angular cli"